# Reversing words in each line a field text contains several lines in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field in table SQL contains text with several line ,the words of each line are inverted
similar to this:

**“it of face the on , Therefore
. people English be should answer the
be won’t England from person a ,said That
of Australian an from different visibly
their open they until ancestry European
.accent English an have  and mouths”**

How can it be corrected :

**“Therefore, on the face of it
the answer should be English people.
That said, a person from England won’t be
visibly different from an Australian of
European ancestry until they open their
mouths and have an English accent.”**

Comment: SQL Server is _not_ the tool for this job, you need something like Python, Java, Perl, etc.  Fix this problem outside of your database.

Answer (score 0):

using functions such as SUBSTRING,CHARINDEX for splitting string and REVERSE to reverse your string in SQL could be beneficial.however,your string is very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

using function SUBSTRING,CHARINDEX in WHILE loop on string and cursor in table field

```
declare @str nvarchar(max)
declare @hokm bigint 
declare @enter_tedad int
declare cur cursor 

for select  id,EPDesc,LEN(CAST (EHPDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
    - LEN(REPLACE(CAST (EPDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), CHAR(13), '')) from table1 where EPDesc!=''  and EPDesc2 is null
    

open cur
fetch next from cur into @hokm,@str,@enter_tedad
print @hokm
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin

DECLARE @enter13_10 INT ,
    @str_tmp NVARCHAR(MAX)= N'' 
WHILE @enter_tedad > 0
    OR LEN(@str) > 0
BEGIN   
    SET @enter13_10 = CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), @str, 1);

    PRINT '@enter13_10';    
    PRINT @enter13_10;

    IF @enter13_10 > 0
    BEGIN       
        SET @str_tmp = SUBSTRING(@str, 1,
                                 CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), @str, @enter13_10))
            +' '+ @str_tmp;

        SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), @str, @enter13_10) + 1,
                             800);
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN       
        SET @str_tmp = @str +' '+ @str_tmp;
    
        SET @str = '';

    END;
        SET @enter_tedad = @enter_tedad - 1;
END;
print @str_tmp
update table1 set EPDesc2=@str_tmp where id=@hokm
set @str_tmp=N''

    fetch next from cur into @hokm,@str,@enter_tedad
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```